# JSON model does not load correctly in three js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load the json model in this url : https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=3c08fd2e9d4a4a01ab86ffc23ffbe347 into my three js file using this code :

```
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load("models/unique-house.json",function ( obj ) {

        scene.add( obj );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

        scene.traverse(function(children){
            objects.push(children);
        });

    });
```

But I am getting only the object named Stone as the output, all the other objects are not added. The console.log statement prints this object in this link :

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e6b9edcd19a24c359ec07415d47beb52

And my output is :
[image: only this plane]

The expected output is :
[image: house]

I downloaded the model from https://clara.io/view/dab2e20a-3ba1-46fe-9cde-7e4e75a1aca5

Can anyone please tell me if there is a problem with the json file or if there is a problem in the way the json file has been parsed?

Comment: The model uses a deprecated geometry format, so you have to include [THREE.LegacyJSONLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/deprecated/LegacyJSONLoader.js) into your project. Apart from that, the shared JSON only contains a single plane definition and not the geometry of a house.

Comment: The materials array contains all the information about the house, right?

Comment: It seems so. But the respective geometry data are missing.